# How do I test the performance of my webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization

Are there any tools, websites that will allow you to test your website performance like load time, render time and what can be done to make it better. I know there is an addon called YSLOW for firebug. but I am just wondering if there is anything more than that.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/pagespeed/ can be worth a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[New Relic](http://newrelic.com/) does end to end monitoring. Standard version is free for Rackspace customers.

Most browsers have a built in inspector. At least Opera, Chrome, and IE.

Firebug for Firefox

[Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) will help you inspect actual HTTP requests

Google's done some work with [Page Speed](https://developers.google.com/pagespeed/)

Of course you know about YSlow, which follow's [Yahoo's Guidelines](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

[Pingdom](http://pingdom.com)'s monitoring solution will tell you worldwide how fast it can get TTLB, and they give you one free check.

[Blitz](http://blitz.io/) will let you do load testing

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome - right click on a page on your website and choose "Inspect element"

Some Network stats for this page:

[image: ChromeNetworkScreenshot]

And an Audit on this page that shows possible optimizations:

[image: ChromeAuditScreenshot]

Comment: And then how will it shoe me optimizations

Comment: Good question - not sure if Chrome will show optimizations or not but it will show you underneath the Network section Sizes and Times on objects.  Considering how awesome Google's development tools are I'm thinking that there's probably some sort of optimization information but just not sure off the top of my head...

Comment: And looking a little deeper there's an Audits section that you can run on the page you're on.  Just ran it on this page and I got things like "Combine external JavaScript" & "Leverage browser caching" back.

Answer (score 2):

My personal favorite: [webpagetest.org](http://webpagetest.org/), a free online service which allows to:

- provide your URL (and username/pwd if needed)
- choose browser (ie 7, 8 or 9, chrome or firefox, depending on location)
- choose connection type
- choose location from which to run the test
- choose the number of runs
- ... (a whole lot of other configuration)

and which produces:

- detailed view of each request (with nice graphs)
- solid advice on how to improve

[image: screenshot from webpagetest, not mine to be clear]